# How do I create an animation in cocos2d without a spritesheet?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have multiple images that are the size of the fullscreen, and the object moves around in it while everything else is transparent. So all I would need to animate it is to somehow constantly swap the image that is loaded. Is there any way to do this? all the examples I have found use spritesheets

Comment: You should use spritesheets (ie texture atlas). This will give your app a performance boost as well as reduce memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about cocos2D and wether or not objective-c works with it... when I first started I would swap out with an NSTimer and an integer keeping track of the frame I was on.... later on I found out about this animation process:

```
    NSArray *imageFrames = [NSArrayarray];
    imageFrames = [[NSArrayalloc] initWithObjects:
                 [UIImageimageNamed:@"image1.png"],
                 [UIImageimageNamed:@"image2.png"],
                 [UIImageimageNamed:@"image3.png"],
                 nil];
    imagesImage.animationImages = imageFrames;
    imagesImage.animationDuration = 0.5;
    imagesImage.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [imageFrames release];
```

And

```
[imagesImage startAnimating];
```